# Execute a batch file inside javafx project without showing command prompt window

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx, cmd, java-11

i have the following code that execute a batch file located inside my javafx project,

```
public class AppController {

@FXML
private void handleExecuteBatchFile(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("enter");
    try {
        File file;
        file = new File(getClass().getResource("/batch/install.bat").getPath().substring(1));
        String[] command = { "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "", "/b", file.getName() };
        System.out.println("file.getName(): "+file.getName());
        System.out.println("file.getParentFile(): " + file.getParentFile());
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(command, null, file.getParentFile());
        System.out.println("exit");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("interupted IOException" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

my batch file install.bat is the following:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to batch scripting!
set xa=\\192.168.4.20\xfcompt\DA
set xal=C:\xfcompt\DA\
xcopy /s %xa%  %xal%
exit
```

I use \b parameter in the start command to execute the command in a hidden way,

the weird thing is that the copy doesn't complete until i close the application then it continue the copy process.

but the copy is successful when i use \min parameter which minimize the command Prompt window.

How can i use \b parameter i dont want to show the command prompt window?

Comment: The best way to avoid this problem is to refrain from using a batch file entirely for this.  Use [Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) and [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) (and Files.createDirectories) instead.